# how to check out git repository of other user and commit through my local machine

Tags: git

I am new to Git.
I have created a repository in my git account.
we are a team of  four and will be working on the same repository.

What should I do so that other team members can have the copy of my repository on their local machine and they can also commit in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleagues need to `git clone` the repository, once you've hosted it somewhere. This can be your own host, or you can use GitHub or Bitbucket.

They will get a remote set up for them - they will then push their changes via that remote.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps need to be followed:

1)They need to create your rsa key first and which needs to be copied to github. Try the following [link](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.in/2010/03/create-ssh-public-key-for-github.html)

2) git clone repo_url

Answer (score 0):

For teamwork, I advice that you can configure a git server to store you repository. And then, push you own repository to the remote server, so that others can pull the repository to their local machine and do their work. It will be a better way for team development.